# Attempting to merge DRI documents but the source document is not compatable with the feeder document

Tags: dspace

I recently encountered the following error in dspace 1.8.2 when I try to access the login page.

> Could not read resource
>   file:///Users/maatary/Dev/dspace/webapps/xmlui/aspects/protodocument.xml
>   context:/null - 96:0   context:/null -
>   95:0   context:/null - 314:0     context:/null - 77:0  
>   context:/null - 65:0   context:/null -
>   149:0  context:/null - 57:0  context:/null - 51:0    context:/null -
>   1038:0     context:/null - 287:0     context:/null - 286:0   context:/null - 284:0    
>   context:/null - 182:0  context:/null -
>   61:0   context:/null -
>   59:0   context:/null - 154:0    
>   context:/null - 153:0 
>   context:/null - 109:0  context:/null
>   - 98:0     context:/null - 293:0     context:/null - 269:0    context:/null -
>   82:0   context:/null - 56:0 
>   context:/null - 173:0  context:/null -
>   157:0  context:/null - 136:0    
>   context:/null - 88:0   context:/null -
>   25:0   context:/null - 17:0 
>   context:/null - 590:0  context:/null -
>   105:0  context:/null -
>   104:0  context:/null - 49:0 
>   context:/null - 47:0   context:/null -
>   20:0   context:/null - 607:0    
>   context:/null - 312:0  context:/null
>   - 156:0    context:/null - 66:0  context:/null - 40:0  context:/null -
>   342:0  context:/null - 132:0     context:/null - 120:0   context:/null
>   - 85:0     context:/null - 84:0  context:/null - 83:0     context:/null
>   - 207:0    context:/null - 201:0   context:/null -
>   194:0  context:/null - 155:0    context:/null - 91:0   context:/null - 88:0  context:/null -
>   33:0   context:/null - 32:0    
>   context:/null - 727:0

Java stacktrace [hide]

> org.dspace.app.xmlui.wing.WingException: Attempting to merge DRI
>   documents but the source document is not compatable with the feeder
>   document.     at
>   org.dspace.app.xmlui.wing.AbstractWingTransformer.startElement(AbstractWingTransformer.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.startElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.cocoon.environment.internal.EnvironmentChanger.startElement(EnvironmentStack.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.sax.XMLTeePipe.startElement(XMLTeePipe.java:87)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.aalto.in.XmlScanner.fireSaxStartElement(XmlScanner.java:674)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.aalto.sax.SAXParserImpl.fireStartTag(SAXParserImpl.java:521)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.aalto.sax.SAXParserImpl.fireEvents(SAXParserImpl.java:438)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.aalto.sax.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:370)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.core.xml.impl.JaxpSAXParser.parse(JaxpSAXParser.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.core.xml.impl.JaxpSAXParser.parse(JaxpSAXParser.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.source.util.SourceUtil.parse(SourceUtil.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.generate(FileGenerator.java:136)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.generate(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.processXMLPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.process(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:750)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.process(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.toSAX(SitemapSource.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.cocoon.components.source.util.SourceUtil.toSAX(SourceUtil.java:111)
>     at

.....

Comment: I haven't seen occur before, but I can tell you it's happening here: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/59f07bd4dab763eaff050a04ce65dd87a4ac84c6/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/wing/AbstractWingTransformer.java#L195

Comment: Error message spelling was [fixed on Apr 20, 2012](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/commit/b8cefdce04c2c68f56d8bced6421052eea0159fe#diff-b744d4b5493a9faa5f64afd19613ae70R195) and included in DSpace 1.5.0. With the spelling error, it means you're using DSpace 1.4.2 or older, from **May 12, 2009**, not DSpace 1.8.2.